# ajaxStatus for specific component only

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces 3.2 with JSF 2.0.

I'm using a

```
<p:commandButton action="#{myBackingBean.action}" value="press me" />
```

And this for ajaxStatus:

```
<p:ajaxStatus onstart="statusDialog.show();"
      onsuccess="statusDialog.hide();"
      rendered="#{myBackingBean.ajaxStatusRendered}"
      id="ajaxStatusField" />

    <p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="statusDialog"
      header="#{myBackingBean.ajaxStatusHeader}"
      rendered="#{myBackingBean.ajaxStatusRendered}" id="ajaxPanel"
      draggable="false" closable="false">
      <p:graphicImage value="./images/ajaxloader.gif" />
    </p:dialog>
```

I've got lots of other primefaces components also on the same page, but I only want the p:ajaxStatus to render when this specific button is pressed. Any good solution to this? The ajaxStatus renders on every ajax event..

Comment: If you had a few amount of buttons you could set on them global="false" and leave the desired button without this setting, that way all other buttons wouldn't trigger the p:ajaxStatus while the desired button would... (but i guess that's does not fit to your case...)

Comment: Brilliant, it worked, thank you very much! Write it in an answer, so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have a few amount of buttons, you could set on them `global="false"` and leave the desired button without this setting.

This way all other buttons wouldn't trigger the `p:ajaxStatus` while the desired button would.