# PrimeFaces 7.0 DataTable object reset() method doesn't clear selected row(s)

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I encountered a bug (I think) in the dataTable.reset() method, it works fine, it resets "sorts", "filters", and all made to the datatable except the selected rows.

I have a datatable on a dialog, everytime I open this dialog I need the datatable to be reset, so in the ManagedBean I get this dataTable and call `.reset()` method, it was all good until I started making all the possible tests, and I found out that if you "sort" or "filter" on any of the columns of the table, and then select one of the rows, and close the dialog and re-open it, my reset method will reset everything except the selected rows, I was reading https://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/7.0/org/primefaces/component/datatable/DataTable.html to see if there was a method that could do something like `.unselectAllRows()` but couldn't find anything :/, I tried doing `dataTable.setValue(null)`, or `dataTable.resetValue()`, but no success also, anyone knows if there is a method that can unselect all rows also?

Also its curious that the reset works on clearing selected rows but only if I haven't "sort" or "filter" in the datatable.

In PrimeFaces source (https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/datatable/DataTable.java) I found the code of the DataTable resetValue(), resetRows() and reset() methods and it looks like this:

```
 public void resetValue() {
        setValue(null);
        setFilteredValue(null);
        setFilters(null);
    }

    public void reset() {
        resetValue();
        setFirst(0);
        reset = true;
        setValueExpression("sortBy", getDefaultSortByVE());
        setSortFunction(getDefaultSortFunction());
        setSortOrder(getDefaultSortOrder());
        setSortByVE(null);
        setSortColumn(null);
        setSortField(null);
        setDefaultSort(true);
        clearMultiSortMeta();
    }

    public void resetRows() {
        getStateHelper().remove("rows");
    }
```

Can't see something there that can reset the "selected rows" :p

My method to reset a datatable which im calling everytime I open the dialog that shows the datatable:

```
public static void resetTabla(String pIdDataTable) {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        UIViewRoot root = context.getViewRoot();
        final UIComponent[] uiComponentTabla = new UIComponent[1];
        // Busca el componente en alguno de los xhtml
        root.visitTree(VisitContext.createVisitContext(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()), new VisitCallback() {
            @Override
            public VisitResult visit(VisitContext context, UIComponent component) {
                // Si el id del componente es igual al id que llego por parametro
                // Entonces asigna uiComponentTabla[0] a ese componente
                if (component.getId().equals(pIdDataTable)) {
                    uiComponentTabla[0] = component;
                    // Esto le indica al visitTree que ya puede dar por terminada la busqueda
                    return VisitResult.COMPLETE;
                }
                // Esto le inidca al visitTree que debe descender al subarbol del componente
                // actual
                return VisitResult.ACCEPT;
            }
        });
        if (uiComponentTabla[0] != null) {
            try {
                DataTable dataTable = (DataTable) uiComponentTabla[0];
                dataTable.reset();
                PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("PF('" + dataTable.getWidgetVar() + "').unselectAllRows();" + "PF('"
                        + dataTable.getWidgetVar() + "').clearFilters();");
                PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update(uiComponentTabla[0].getClientId());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: [mcve] please and the source is open regarding javascript (api) functions

Comment: @Kukeltje I will upload the minimal example tomorrow mate, what do you mean with "the source is open regarding javascript (api) functions"? :s what source

Comment: The PrimeFaces source. It is an open-source project

Comment: @Kukeltje I checked the source and I think that the method reset or the others don't have something to remove the selected rows, is right? check my edit (im working on the mcre).

Comment: @Kukeltje im experiencing another bug man Idk what the hell is wrong with the reset method, apart from that, if you select the sorting column twice, and you close the dialog with the datatable, and reopen it, the datatable sorts will appear normal (the arrow up and down normal), but the sort will actually stay ascending or descending not normal like when you refresh page and open it :/ im gonna add my reset datatable method

Comment: Why are you doing all the things you are doing? You might be trying to create a workaround for a workaround instead of removing the first one...  And the selected rows is something that is in your bean, not a part of the datatable. So you need to reset that in your code... Hint: Instead of your own treewalker etc, use omnifaces (you should use it for other things too: It has `Components.findComponent(String clientId)`  http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/3.3/org/omnifaces/util/Components.html and http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Components

Comment: @Kukeltje can't use omnifaces right now mate :( im doing this because it was the solution to using all that jquery that they have on the .js file I told you some days ago, if I use that .js I will get the growl bug dissapiaring fast, so I though that the reset() method would do all that, but its missing some things like unselect rows and this current bug of the sorts, how can I reset that in my code? you mean java server side like im trying there?

Comment: @Kukeltje look what I had to add on the method to make it work like I want, but I shouldn't need to do that, reset method should do that for me, I shouldn't need to use that executeScript there

Comment: @Kukeltje mate you don't know if there is a method that can do what that execute script is doing? like the reset() one?

Comment: This a workaround on a workaround on a workaround. Make the growl not autoupdate and do the rest in a normal way.You are being very creative and investigative, but overly complex. And since there is no [mcve] of the ORIGINAL problem, I cannot suggest how to do things otherwise. http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @Kukeltje the problem is I don't know whats the original problem mate, this thing is so full of workaround, I think principal problem is that ajaxstatus being called on everysingle event, im just like going through a cave of darkness on this migration and trying to kill each "monster" that appears as correctly as possible but im gonna start filling this of workarounds too, I will try to do the mcre but it will take some time mate, thank you for all your help its being very helpful, wouldn't gone so far without it :).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295153/ajaxstatus-for-specific-component-only

Comment: @Kukeltje that works mate, but I showed it to my partner and he says thats not a right solution because I would be leaving parts of code with ajax and other without ajax and he says that in the future is bad and can make problems, but I don't think so lol, he says what if in the future another developer needs to use ajax on that button

Comment: No, it is not with vs without ajax. If your partner does not understand that from the Q/A I can imagine all sorts of different (bad) workarounds occurring. And there might be other solutions as well,

Comment: @Kukeltje Hmm can you explain a bit better what global="false" is doing? because it works like that but I also decided that I can just executeScript too, but my reset method isn't as useless as I though, because I also need to use it to reset all the other stuff of the datatable :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196900/discussion-between-kukeltje-and-bugsforbreakfast).

Comment: @Kukeltje Okay I will be in chat mate join when you can :)

Comment: @Kukeltje Can you check what I posted in chat? to see if I understood

Comment: @Kukeltje, look at the chat mate, and also I did what you said of don't using autoupdate on growl, updating it when it needs to be updated and it works mate but my partner says "Noo then we have to do the same an all our 20 screens, its too much try to leave it as it is autoupdate", but I don't know how to make him understand that shit wont work like that xD or it will be alot of workarounds to make it work because it is too much ajax thingys goin on

Comment: @Kukeltje hey mate thanks for reply on the chat I understand now why clearFilters gives problems and why unselectRows doesn't but please check again I posted something im curious about because clearFilters doesn't give problems when called outside the method please check chat

Comment: Code is unreadable in chat. Please create a new question since it effectively is one

Comment: @Kukeltje what should be the new question title?

Comment: _"Different behaviour of clearFilters ajax update when used in two different ways"_ or something like this

Comment: @Kukeltje Okay brother